# Looking for 80's sci-fi with anthropomorphic aliens that looked like white (?) tiger-people & perceived/spoke of everything in the present tense?

Tags: story-identification

I don't have much more information than that only that I'm almost certain I read it before 1984, it was a library book and very possibly YA sci-fi, whatever that was called then. Thank you.

Comment: Definitely a book then, not a short story?  Aliens and not modified Earth animals (or people)?

Comment: It's possible it was a short story but it was definitely in a book and again I'm not certain but pretty sure they were aliens. I was 11 then, I'm almost 50 now LOL

Comment: Kind of locals from Ensign Flandry by Poul Anderson

Comment: CJ Cherryh's [Chanur Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chanur_novels)?